# AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'iloc'

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I run this code:

```
for no_confi in range(len(df)): 
    if df['Confidence_Index_Status'][no_confi] == 0:
        df = df.iloc[no_confi,2:4] = np.nan
        df = df.iloc[no_confi,5:] = np.nan
```

and get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'iloc'
```

The code should reset all values to NaN if the Vonfidence_Index_Status is 0. Two columns (Timestemp and Altitude) should be hold.

How i can fix this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skip the first `df =`:

```
for no_confi in range(len(df)): 
    if df['Confidence_Index_Status'][no_confi] == 0:
        df.iloc[no_confi,2:4] = np.nan
        df.iloc[no_confi,5:] = np.nan
```

An faster solution would be:

```
df.loc[df['Confidence_Index_Status'] == 0, 2:] = np.nan
```

Comment: Ah, great thanks. Is there a faster way to do that?